# btsync doesn't start on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, bittorrent

btsync 1.4.103 doesn't start as daemon on 14.04 x86_64. Here are my steps:

1. Downloaded.
2. `sudo mv btsync /usr/local/bin`.
3. `btsync --dump-sample-config > ~/.config/btsync/btsync.conf`
4. `btsync`

At this point I expected some output, like pid, but it printed absolutely nothing and exited. Furthermore, if I run `echo $?` immediately after btsync, it prints "1", so there some error. Then I launched `btsync --log ./log.txt` and it didn't create any log file.

`dmesg` shows nothing related to btsync. It simply doesn't start as daemon and silently exits. Only config dumping and --help are working. I have also tried `glibc2.3` version, also without success. Google didn't help.

Have I missed something? Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reason** - BTSync tries to create additional files/folders in folder with `btsync` executable. In my case inside of `/usr/local/bin`. Since it was launched without root privileges - it failed to start.

**Solution** - BTSync must be placed and then started only from folder where it can create its own files/folders.